# How do I get all files in a directory with a certain extension in a format that allows me to use it in a dropdown or radiolist?

Tags: c#

I have a directory called C:\Somewhere.
In C:\Somewhere, I have config files of various extensions.

How do I get all files with some certain extensions in a format usable in a dropdown or similar object?

My Current Code:

```
var ext = new List<string> { "yml", "config", "properties", "txt", "yaml" };
var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(servDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(s => ext.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

As far as I can tell this is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the file extension with the dot before the extension.
So to make your code work you need just:

```
var ext = new List<string> { ".yml", ".config", ".properties", ".txt", ".yaml" };
```

From MSDN

> **Path.GetExtension**
>   Return Value Type: System.String The extension of the specified path
>   **(including the period ".")**, or null, or String.Empty. If path is null,
>   GetExtension returns null. If path does not have extension
>   information, GetExtension returns String.Empty.